# how to automate the creation of a variable with tidyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

Consider this simple example:

```
mytib <- tibble(city_name1 = c('nyc', 'DC'),
       city_name2 = c('US', 'US'),
       planet_name1 = c('earth', 'moon'),
       planet_name2 = c('solar', 'solar'))

# A tibble: 2 x 4
  city_name1 city_name2 planet_name1 planet_name2
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr>        <chr>       
1 nyc        US         earth        solar       
2 DC         US         moon         solar
```

I am trying to automate the creation of a few simple variables that use `tidyr`. Specifically, I am simply adding the two character variables `_name1` and `_name2` for each topic. As below:

```
> mytib %>% 
+   tidyr::unite(complete_city,
+                c('city_name1', 'city_name2'), remove = FALSE) %>% 
+   tidyr::unite(complete_planet,
+                c('planet_name1', 'planet_name2'), remove = FALSE) 
# A tibble: 2 x 6
  complete_city city_name1 city_name2 complete_planet planet_name1 planet_name2
  <chr>         <chr>      <chr>      <chr>           <chr>        <chr>       
1 nyc_US        nyc        US         earth_solar     earth        solar       
2 DC_US         DC         US         moon_solar      moon         solar
```

The issue is that I would like to automate this. That is, looping over the topics `city` and `planet`. How can I do that? I tried the following with no success:

```
for(topic in c('city', 'planet')){
  
 mytib <-  mytib %>% 
    tidyr::unite('complete_{{topic}}',
                 c('{{topic}}_name1', '{{topic}}_name2'), remove = FALSE)
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use a custom function together with `purrr::reduce()`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

mytib <- tibble(city_name1 = c('nyc', 'DC'),
                city_name2 = c('US', 'US'),
                planet_name1 = c('earth', 'moon'),
                planet_name2 = c('solar', 'solar'))


myunite <- function(df, x) {
  tidyr::unite(df, !! paste0("complete_", x),
               paste0(x, "_name", 1:2),
               # alternatively: starts_with(x), 
               remove = FALSE)
}

mytib %>% 
  reduce(c("planet", "city"), myunite, .init = .)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   complete_city city_name1 city_name2 complete_planet planet_name1 planet_name2
#>   <chr>         <chr>      <chr>      <chr>           <chr>        <chr>       
#> 1 nyc_US        nyc        US         earth_solar     earth        solar       
#> 2 DC_US         DC         US         moon_solar      moon         solar
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>
Another approach is to rename some variables and use `dplyr::across()` instead of `tidyr::unite`.

```r
mytib %>% 
  rename_with(~ gsub("1$", "", .)) %>% 
  mutate(across(matches("_[A-z]*$"), 
                ~ str_c(get(cur_column()),"_",get(str_c(cur_column(), 2))),
                .names = "complete_{col}"))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   city_name city_name2 planet_name planet_name2 complete_city_n~
#>   <chr>     <chr>      <chr>       <chr>        <chr>           
#> 1 nyc       US         earth       solar        nyc_US          
#> 2 DC        US         moon        solar        DC_US           
#> # ... with 1 more variable: complete_planet_name <chr>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: thanks but the point is to be able to program with `tidyr` and `dplyr` in the new versions. I am kind of struggling with the syntax.

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ I totally get your point. It’s a good question, and I have other ideas, but the only one working out really quickly was the one above. I will update my answer later.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a list of all the variable prefixes that you want to unite

```
my_names <- names(mytib) %>% 
  stringr::str_sub(., 1, -2) %>% 
  unique(.)
```

2. Create a function to unite the named variables. You can get fancier with the creation of `new_name` if you want

```
my_unite <- function(name, dat, remove = FALSE) {
  new_name = paste0("complete_", name)
  tidyr::unite(dat, !!new_name, starts_with(name), remove = remove) %>% 
    select(!!new_name, starts_with(name))
}
```

3. Combine the names and the function and bind everything back together.

```
purrr::map_dfc(my_names, my_unite, dat = mytib)
```